# Writing rows from a DataTable is creating a run-on write: how do I preserve each line as it is written?

Tags: c#

Given this code:

```
using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(file))
{
    for (int r = 0; r < originalDataTable.Rows.Count; r++)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < originalDataTable.Columns.Count; c++)
        {
            var rowValueAtColumn = originalDataTable.Rows[r][c].ToString();

            var valueToWrite = string.Format(@"{0}{1}", rowValueAtColumn, "\t");

            if (c != originalDataTable.Columns.Count)
                sw.Write(valueToWrite);
            else 
                sw.Write(valueToWrite + @"\n");
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to write a DataRow back to a file one row at a time; however, the file it is creating is creating a run-on sentence where all the data being written to the file is just in one line. There should be 590 individual lines not just one.

What do I need to add to the code above so that my lines are broken out as they are in the data table? My code just doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sw.Write(valueToWrite + @"\n");` is wrong. Because of the `@` it is not entering a newline, you are writing the character `\` then the character `n`.

You want to do either `sw.Write(valueToWrite + "\n");` or have the program put a new line in for you by doing `sw.WriteLine(valueToWrite)`, however that will enter [Environment.NewLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline.aspx) which is `\r\n` on windows.

---

However you can make your code even simpler by inserting the row the separator outside of the column for loop. I also defined the two separators at the top of the loop in case you want to ever change them (What will the program you are sending this to do when you hit some data that has a `\t` or a `\n` in the text itself?), and a few other small tweaks to make the code easier to read.

```
string colSeperator = "\t";
string rowSeperator = "\n";

using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(file))
{
    for (int r = 0; r < originalDataTable.Rows.Count; r++)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < originalDataTable.Columns.Count; c++)
        {
            sw.Write(originalDataTable.Rows[r][c])

            sw.Write(colSeperator);
        }
        sw.Write(rowSeperator);
    }
}
```

---

Here is another similification just to show other ways to do it (now that you don't need to check `originalDataTable.Columns.Count`)

```
string colSeperator = "\t";
string rowSeperator = "\n";

using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(file))
{
    foreach (DataRow row in originalDataTable.Rows)
    {
        foreach (object value in row.ItemArray))
        {
            sw.Write(value)
            sw.Write(colSeperator);
        }
        sw.Write(rowSeperator);
    }
}
```

Comment: You raise a good point in your parenthetical question. However, the tab delimited file that the DataTable is built from and that I am "rehydrating" from the datatable is just a single row of headers of chemical names followed by row after row of numerical data (doubles).

Comment: Given my code above, is there a reason why my else statement is never being hit? I just now placed a breakpoint there and realized that is pretty much the start of my problem other than what you have shown me is additionally a problem. Even if I insert an else `if(c == originalDataTable.Columns.Count)` the condition still isnt hit.

Comment: @IsaiahNelson Yea, C is 0 indexed so it goes from 0 to `originalDataTable.Columns.Count - 1`, chaining your if statement to `if(c == (originalDataTable.Columns.Count - 1))` would fix it.

Comment: Thanks for the additional example. If I could +1 your post again, I would.

Answer (score 2):

Change  `sw.Write()` to  `sw.WriteLine()`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.writeline.aspx